# My Navbar Brand wont Align Right in my Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid"> <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
            <!---Collapse-->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse"> <a class="navbar-brand"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Gvaldi</a>
                    <div class="navbar-nav"> <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a> <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Features</a> <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Pricing</a> </li>
                        </ul>
    </nav> a:link { color: white; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: none; } .a { font-family: "Times New Roman", "Helvetica", "Verdana"; }
```

**I'm trying to float my navbar brand tag  to the right of my navigation bar**

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to delete one of  tags. And you can set like this.

```css
a:link {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.a {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", "Helvetica", "Verdana";
}

.navbar-brand {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
                </button>
    <!---Collapse-->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Gvaldi</a>
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a> <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Features</a> <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```